# How to refresh listview in fragment when onbackpressed()

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I want to refresh listview fragmentA when back pressed

> example:
>
> I click onitem in listview in FragmentA to FragmentB
>
> and when I click back (in Activity) in FragmentB ,I want to refresh
>   listview FragmentA.

sorry My english is not good.

How to set onViewCreated OR onResume in FragmentA ???

and My activity

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
```

MyFragmentA

```
 @Override
    public void setItems(ArrayList<NotificationListModel> items,String last_page) {
        Log.d("NotificationFragment", "setItems ");
        this.notificationListModels=items;
        this.last_page=last_page;

        for (NotificationListModel notificationListModel: notificationListModels){
            notificationListModelArrayList.add(notificationListModel);
        }
        getData();
        if (getActivity()!=null) {
            int currentPosition = getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition();
            adapNotificationList = new AdapNotificationList(getActivity(), notificationListModelArrayList);
            setListAdapter(adapNotificationList);
            adapNotificationList.notifyDataSetChanged();
            getListView().setSelection(currentShowList);
            getListView().setSelectionFromTop(currentPosition + 1, 0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Override onResume in Fragment A and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() or the function which is handling data refresh of your listview.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    //OR
    callDataRefreshFunction();

}
```

You do not need to handle onBackPressed in Activity.

Comment: Umm my code I set adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); in setItems() it's Wrong? please check my code ,i editted a post

Comment: adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() redraws the views in ListView when it is called. So calling it after setting Adapter is unnecessary and can be removed.

Comment: Please give example for me T.T

Answer (score 0):

First check fragmentB is visible or not if visible then

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(fragmentb.isVisible())
         {
           //update listview of fragment a
           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
         }
        else
          super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Comment: my code I set adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); in setItems() it's Wrong? please check my code ,i editted a post

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are loading data from server into the listview. If so and you want to refresh the listview on back press then just don't override the backpressed method. Just remove this code from fragment B.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In fragment you need to refresh after back pressed try add this:

```js
 @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
            if (FragmentCreated) {  //FragmentCreated = True in procedure onCreateView
                
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.detach(this).attach(this).commit();
                //This reloads current fragment
               
            }

        }else{
            // fragment is no longer visible
        }
    }
```